# Dishwasher leaking when we add item during cycle

Tags: leak, dishwasher

We have a Kenmore dishwasher (model 665.13749) that leaks when we open it during a cycle to add an item. We are doing this according to the directions, opening the door very slightly until the washer stops.  When we open the door all the way after it stops spraying, water dribbles onto the floor, apparently from the bottom of the door--not a huge amount, but more than a few drops. In addition, if we reach behind the panel at the bottom of the door, the insulation is wet.  Earlier in the year we had a problem with leaking during the wash cycle, but after several repairs under our service contract that problem seems to have been fixed.  I called today to report the current problem of leakage when we add an item during the cycle, and was told this was normal.  We have had this dishwasher for several years, and, with the exception of a few drops on occasion, nobody in the household has ever noticed water leaking when adding an item during a cycle.  Is this normal?  Our service contract runs out in August and if this isn't normal, we would like to make sure the problem is fixed.

Comment: I wonder is the washer slightly over filling? When you break the seal it is just over flowing a bit?

Comment: We checked for that, and it doesn't appear that it is.  The water seems to always dribble out under the left side of the door but the insulation is wet on the right.  I'm just wondering if this is normal, as stated by the agent we called.  It wasn't doing this before we started having the original problem with it leaking during the cycle.

Comment: Ok well I gave my best had one that had a leve sensor go bad and one that was not level after a service. Hope you get better answers